# How to set height for elements in a <section>

Tags: html, css, height

I use `<section>` to display set of contents in my website in this [**ADDRESS**](http://www.aalulbaytisp.com/). in the first page of website there is a header and its height is known, but the `<div>` in the bottom which contains the slideshow has an unknown height, but it must cover the rest of the `<section>`. how can I set `height` for this `<div>` such that it covers the whole bottom of the page?

---

**UPDATE:** 
by setting `height:100%` it works but I want it to be exactly what its size must be base on the screen size. because I'm going to vertically center the slideshow, if I set the bottom `div` height to 100% the slideshow wont be vertically center. here is the code

```
<section id="s1">
    <div id="header-top"><?php include 'header-top.php'; ?></div>
    <div id="s1-container">
        <div id="frontpage_slideshow">
            <?php include 'slideshow.php' ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this is css code

```
#header-top {
height: 105px;
width: 100%;
background: url("../images/header-top/header-top-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
direction: rtl
}

section {
height: 100%
}

#s1-container {
background: url('../images/front-page/header-row.jpg') repeat scroll 50%
    0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center
}
```

Comment: Give it a class and set `height:100%`?

Comment: Please post your code within the question, otherwise this will be useless to any future visitors.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I gave a link to my website !\

Comment: @Drupalist that's the problem. When you've fixed your website the problem will no longer be visible. You should provide the code within the question so that future users will be able to know what the question was about. Otherwise this may as well be closed.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Everything in your provided code works good http://jsfiddle.net/tQ29b/ What is goal with the website? Do you want to put the slideshow in the center of the section or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use display: table, table-row and table-cell.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/TQxaW/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div id="header" class="content">Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div id="section" class="content">Section</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.block {
    display: table-row;
}

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#header {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but how do I can vertically center the slideshow when using `table` display?

Comment: Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.content` definition. Please, mark answer as accepted, if everything works. Good luck!